# Is there a way to rotate a map view in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, geojson, qgis

I have a floor plan map that I have georeferenced in QGIS, drew polygons for the rooms over the floor plan, and exported the resulting coordinates and other data as GeoJSON to load into a table in a sql server database using a script I wrote.

I'm currently displaying the data for the floor plan in a map in SSRS. At first I thought I was just going to be able to rotate the polygons to straighten out how it looks in SSRS, but it turns out I'm going to need to rotate the entire map view about 115 degrees clockwise.

Aside from inaccurately georeferencing the floor plan in QGIS so it will appear the way I need it to in SSRS, does anyone know of a way to do this? I'm open to anything. Other software recommendations, etc. Not having much luck finding solutions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem, my solution for this ended up as follows from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DKxAJ1xsrQ):

- Connect to the database in QGIS to display the data I had for the floor plan that had been loaded into SQL Server.
- Export the database layer, save as GeoJSON, making sure to add the saved file to the map.
- Install the TomBio tools plugin for QGIS.
- Toggle editing on the layer from the newly saved file. Select all the features I needed to rotate with the Select Features by Area button in the new tool strip for the TomBio tools plugin.
- Use Rotate Feature in QGIS to rotate the selected features.
- Save and export the rotated features as GeoJSON to load back into SQL Server.